# List of contacts per User when extending AbstractUser

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a custom user model with some extra fields, among which a contact list of other users. I would like to extend `AbstractUser` instead of creating a new model with a one-to-one link to `User`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    a_custom_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # per-user contact list
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
```

This code doesn't work. Throwing this error during makemigrations.

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.CustomUser' that has not been installed`

The error totally makes sense, but what's the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution just by digging more into the django docs.
The problem is that I cannot use `get_user_model()` before the user model has been created.
The solution is using the class name as a string. So, this code works great:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    a_custom_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # per-user contact list
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField('CustomUser')
```

Comment: In this specific case the use of the string 'self' would be an option too